# Custom split buttons in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to use JQuery Mobile in my next project, but we are facing a problem with the buttons. We are asked to make buttons that have two colors. I have looked at examples on juerymobile.com, search google, even tried bing, but I can't find a good answer.

Could someone give me a pointer how I could make this button in jquery mobile?

[image: split image]